# Running systemd units in user space in debian

Tags: debian, systemd, systemctl, debian-stretch

I'm trying to setup a unit to run on Debian Stretch under a regular user. I connect to it over `ssh`.

I first did this as root (username being the user in question):

```
# loginctl enable-linger username
```

And then when I run:

```
# systemctl --user
```

I get:

```
Failed to connect to bus: Permission denied
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Logout and log back in.

Answer (score 2):

There is another possible solution to this problem on Debian Stretch (at least): if the `libpam-systemd` package is not installed, then PAM never triggers systemd to create a systemd-user daemon.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my in my installation of debian stretch the environment variable `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` was badly configured for all non root users and was set to `/run/user/0`.

Instead it should be set to the id of the current user. To achieve that you can add the following to your `.bashrc`:

`` export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/`id -r -u` ``

Comment: This ought to be set automatically by the system when you login. Probably the solution is in the other answer posted today.